# shader error with texture uniform and gl_FragData

Tags: three.js, opengl-es, shader

I updated my three.js up to 118 and have error with older code parts related to shader : I get 2 types of error : one is when uniform variable is named texture : need to name it anything different from texture . The second one is : gl_FragData is now undeclared identifier (I'm using this in shader to read terrain height). All this was working earlier. Does any one know what happened ?

Comment: The compiler have changed and is less tolerent. Such issue are common when you move from one compiler to another

Comment: remark ; replacing gf_FragData[0] by gl_FragColor wroks but does not explain the problem with gl_FragData

Comment: You maybe upgraded your glsl language, what version are you using ? This is interesting : https://io7m.com/documents/fso-tta/

Comment: No, my version is not à recent one : 4.2

Comment: It's pretty recent. You write '#version 420' at beginning of your sources ?

Comment: Anyway, if you use a version of the GLSL language (different from the OpenGL version before the version 3.2 of OpenGL, after the 3.2 they normalized it to avoid confusion) greater than 1.30, you should use the declarative way and not through the built-in vars.
On this link you can get all the information you need to change your code. https://io7m.com/documents/fso-tta/

Comment: I did not but will look at this ; thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok, it's better to always precise what version of GLSL version you want to use. The language changed a lot accross version !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `r118`, `WebGLRenderer` uses WebGL 2 by default. That means that custom shader code based on `ShaderMaterial` is automatically interpreted as GLSL 3.0 code. Unfortunately, this change can break user code and requires a migration task.

If you don't have a time budget for this, I suggest you use [WebGL1Renderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGL1Renderer) which was introduced with `r118`. This renderer is identical to `WebGLRenderer`, it just forces a WebGL 1 context and thus your code should run as before.

However, if you want to upgrade to WebGL 2, you have to upgrade your shader code to make it GLSL 3.0 conform. That means:

- Since `texture` is a reserved word, you have to rename it to something else.
- `gl_FragData` does not exist by default in GLSL 3.0. You have to define the output color manually. A simple fragment shader looks like so:

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
 
out vec4 outColor;
 
void main() {
   outColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

Comment: OK thank you. I'll update but have a question : FragColor still exists but affect "all rendering buffer " , as the FragData was only one  (if I'm right) ;  does the manual operation "out vec4 outColor " have a similar effect to address a single buffer ?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what you mean but the code I shared above is a 1:1 replacement for the former `gl_FragData`^^.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.